# CSS Deformable text

Tags: css, text, distortion

I need to create a text that adapts to the size of its container DIV, distorting itself to always fill the whole space inside the DIV. So it should be always width=100% and height=100% and resize according to the browser window.

I know this can be done with an image, my doubt is if there is any way to do the same to a editable text, deforming the font shapes itself. Which property should I use?

Thank you in advise.

Comment: I don't think that its possible with HTML+CSS, probably best to use SVG+CSS.

Comment: Depends on the exact requirement but javascript might help - http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

We are going to use Javascript to change dynamically the `font-size` and `line-height`

First, cache the div so that the browser doesn't have to find it every time the window is resized.

```
var $div = $('.foo');
```

Run the following when the window is resized, and also trigger it once to begin with.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
```

Get the current height of the div and save it as a variable.

```
var height = $div.height();
```

Set the `font-size` and `line-height` of the text within the div according to the current height.

```
$div.css({
'font-size': (height/2) + 'px',
'line-height': height + 'px'
})
}).trigger('resize');
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/6tpztvnc/

---

### Option 2

You can use [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js)

FitText makes font-sizes flexible. Use this plugin on your responsive design for ratio-based resizing of your headlines.

---

### Option 3

You can use [slabText.js](https://github.com/freqdec/slabText)

A jQuery plugin for producing big, bold & responsive headlines

Comment: links of options 1 and 2 are the same…

Comment: @philipp is it too late now to say sorry? corrected.

Comment: well… NO, never :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CSS Viewport percentage lengths, this might be what you're looking for: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

I put together a quick container with text that will change size based on the size of the viewport. You can check it out here: http://codepen.io/sktwentysix/pen/GZzvEx

```
<div class="main">
  <p>
    lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum!
  </p>
</div>

.main {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4vw;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

only CSS will not be possible unless the lenght of your text is known.

If it is known, vw units + transform will do .

- Problems : long text on small window could be too small to be read
- Short text on large screen will be awfully stretched

```css
h1 {
  height: 3vw;
  background: #147EBD;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: 10vw;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(1, 0.3);
}
h1 + h1 span {
  line-height: 40vw;
  font-size: 40vw;
  transform: scale(1, 0.08);
  }
```

```html
<h1> <span>longer text to strecth </span></h1>
<h1> <span>short</span></h1>
```

As you can see, javascript will be needed to find out text lenght before to apply a font-size and a proper scale to start with .

It would be wise somehow to still set a max and min font-size so it remains readable at anytime time, and eventually let break a line on small screen.

edit: i did understand 100% of container, not window's height but scale() will do also in this case.